# Is there anyway we can fetch the App permissions and consent?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to fetch these app permissions without login-in or without Accepting.
[image]

Required Urls:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={Application](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=%7BApplication) Id}&state=12345&redirect_uri={redirect url of app}

Please help

Comment: If you are a global admin, you can approve those permissions through the portal or PowerShell. Is that what you are after?

Comment: You are right... once it is approved I can fetch the permissions  ...but it is not possible to approve thousands apps manually.

Comment: You could use a PowerShell script with the AzureAD module to do the consent. You basically need to create app role assignments for each application permission each app requires (one per permission) and OAuth2 permission grants for each delegated permission set required (one per target API). Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-1.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0. Creating those is what running admin consent does.

Comment: @Junnas Thanks for the reply and your answer helped me.. I have found another approach to work on the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command [`az ad app permission admin-consent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-permission-admin-consent) in Azure CLI, it can grant `Application & Delegated` permissions through admin-consent for the app.

So in your case, you could use a loop to run the command to grant permissions. Make sure you have installed the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest), and login with `az login` as an admin in the AAD tenant, then run the commands below.

My sample grant the permissions for all the app in my tenant, it works in Windows, if you want to run it in Linux, use a [loop syntax for bash](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/For_loop), or you can modify it depend on your requirements.

```
$apps = az ad app list --all --query '[].appId' -o tsv
foreach($app in $apps){
    az ad app permission admin-consent --id $app
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not my requirement. I want to fetch permissions based on id (appId, ObjectID, whatever..) whether it is present in my tenant or not. My idea was  like  when I am hitting Url (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={Application Id}&state=12345&redirect_uri={redirect url of app}) so it asks me to Accept the permissions for that application which I am trying to add in the tenant (as in the above screenshot). So I was trying to find if we can get that response with permissions then it would be feasible for me to fetch for unlimited apps.

Comment: @AshishGautam My understanding is you want to batch consent apps from your tenant or other tenants without login? If so, I don't think it is possible. The admin consent url also needs the login, besides, the graph apis used to consent the permission are all tenant id based, you could not use them without tenant id. You could just login with `common` in the url.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and your answer helped me.. I have found another approach to work on the same.

Comment: @AshishGautam If so, you could share it here, it may help others.

Comment: As per my Idea I have used Web scraping through selenium and fetched the permissions.